# Finding the services running on multiple aws ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

Is there a command in the AWS cli to get a list of services running on my ec2 instances?

Normally I log into each ec2 instance individually, and check using Linux commands such as "netstat" or "ps -eaf".

There are around 400 instances, so if I do this manually it takes quite a lot of time. If any AWS commands are there to find the services running without actually logging into the instance, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some luck with [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/). From their docs:

> Run Command provides a simple way of automating common administrative tasks 
>   like executing Shell scripts and commands on Linux [...]
>   Run Command allows you to execute these commands across multiple
>   instances and provides visibility into the results

Answer (score 5):

The AWS Command Line Interface is a tool to manage your AWS services. You cannot use AWS-CLI to manage OS-level service. With AWS-CLI, you can control multiple AWS services from the command line and automate them through scripts.

Hope it helps :-)